# Rendered videos using Blender's Video Editor causes playback glitch when playing one frame at a time in VLC player

Tags: video

When I try to play my rendered video in VLC player using hotkey [E] to see the video frame by frame, the video will eventually get a glitch where I can't go to the next frame anymore, and when I try to play the video normally afterwards, the playback will start from the beginning again while the screen stays frozen until playback time passes the point where the glitch started before.
There isn't any issue when playing video normally.

This only happens to me for videos rendered from Blender's Video Editor.
Other video files play just fine in VLC when I try to use the [E] key to see video frame by frame.

[Blender Files and Rendered Video download link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Gcmz4Y8U2OhWs3tASbMtLwdp0r2Vj--l?usp=share_link)